# Increase Thunderbird timeout for retrieving POP mail

Tags: email, thunderbird

I have a POP mailserver set up in Thunderbird 2.0 that happens to be very slow. It does eventually connect, but I often get a message saying "Connection to pop server *servername* timed out". The message comes up after 10 seconds and I can't see any timeout configured at 10 seconds. I've tried setting the value of the **mail.server.server7.timeout** setting to 300 (7 is the number of that particular mail server in my config), but this doesn't seem to have changed anything. How do I increase the time that Thunderbird waits before it gives up on trying to connect?

Edit: changing the value in Options, Network & Disc, Connection Timeout doesn't help, either. It's already set to 120 seconds, but the connection times out much quicker than that.

Edit 2: the message pops up after only 10 seconds. I've tried going through the config and changing anything that looked like 10 seconds, without success.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting it in the normal options area. If you're on Windows, it would usually be found here:

> Tools > Options > Advanced > Network & Disk Space

If you're on Linux, (as pointed out by [nagul](https://superuser.com/users/4358/nagul)) it would be:

> Edit > Preferences > Advanced > Network & Disk Space

Then adjust the `Connection timeout:` to however many seconds you think should do.

Comment: +1. Edit->Preferences->Advanced->Network & Disk Space on linux.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help. It still times out much quicker than the 120 seconds that I've set that value to.

Comment: Further investigation is in order.

Comment: How do I do further investigation on this?

Comment: Was more of a self reminder to go and see if there were any other options that could be added to this answer to help you out better.

Comment: Well I've timed the timeout - it's 10 seconds. I tried changing any config settings that look like 10 seconds, without success.

Comment: Going to try out some other things, see if the timeout could be set elsewhere and update the answer if something is found that might help your situation.